# Complex numbers

Tags: self-learning, complex-numbers

I would like to learn the subject **'complex numbers'**. My goal is to study this on my own. Are there any good tips, books, sites to study this?

Comment: This will depend on your starting point.  If you have already studied calculus, then the Schaum's Outline volume on Complex Analysis is good for self-study.

Comment: I would avoid Schaum's Outline's; they're close to useless.

Comment: See chapter 5 in [**Elementary Linear Algebra**](http://www.numbertheory.org/book/) by Keith Matthews. Also, reasonably detailed solutions to all the exercises are given at this web page. I've been citing this on-line reference since 1997 or 1998, and it's STILL on the internet!

Comment: Complex numbers as in arithmetic with and properties of numbers of the form $a+bi$ or as in the more advanced complex analysis?

Comment: Would this be more on topic on math.SE?

Comment: I voted to close based on the comment of @tilper: I do not know whether this question is at the Algebra 2 level, or post-secondary Complex Analysis, or ...?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your background and goals. Once this is done your question will be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

May I recommend what I did in the MESE question "[Complex analysis (Applied versus pure)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/4501/511)
(and in this earlier MSE question, "[Visual research problems in geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85244/237)):

---

[image: Needham cover]

---

[image: Figure 13]

---

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the question may be starting from the point of "what are complex numbers" (far below the level of complex analysis). For that purpose, [Wikipedia: Complex Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) is a perfectly acceptable article with plenty of information.

If you're more of a video-type person then [Khan Academy: Intro to Complex Numbers](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/introduction-to-complex-numbers-algebra-2/the-complex-numbers-algebra-2/v/complex-number-intro) might be satisfying for your purposes.